# Duplicate route message error in laravel filamentphp

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, printing, filamentphp

I'm in a quagmire and can't solve the riddle.
In an environment with Laravel 10 and filamentphp 3 I want to create and display an invoice in a new tab.
I have the following route in web.php:

```
Route::prefix('generatePdf')->name('generatePdf.')
     ->group(function () {
         Route::controller(PdfController::class)->group(function () {
             Route::get('/{record}/invoice/printTenantInvoice', 'printTenantInvoice')->name('invoice.print'); // Incident Reports
         });
     });
```

which is invoked by the action in filamentphp table:

```
Action::make(__('Print'))
   ->icon('heroicon-o-printer')
   ->url(fn (Invoices $record): string => route('generatePdf.invoice.print', ['record' => $record]))
   ->openUrlInNewTab(),
```

but when optimizing the cache with "php artisan optimize" it gives me the following error:

```
Unable to prepare route [generate-pdf/{record}/invoice/printTenantInvoice] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [generate-pdf.invoice.print].
```

How do I eliminate the error?

I have tried many ways to avoid the error but I ran out of ideas. I was hoping it could optimize the cache but it continues to throw the error even though the file is generated correctly.

Comment: Do you mean that you get that error when doing `php artisan route:cache`? If you don't cache routes then everything works fine?

Comment: If in that case it gives me the following message: Unable to prepare route [generatePdf/{record}/invoice/printTenantInvoice] for serialization. Another route has 
already been assigned name [generatePdf.invoice.print].